# Android - RecyclerView computeHorizontalScrollOffset giving fake scroll-offset

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Task is to create Player which contains group of images & videos and play with frames as Player-Controller. See the Below image
[image]

1. Center part is the CustomView which render image/video at the runtime.
2. Player-Controller is the recylerview which contains frame of each image/video.

> Problem - I want to get the Horizontal-Scroll-Pixel on recyclerview scroll

```
private float computeHorizontalScrollOffset() {
    int xOffset = rvHootFrame.computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
    int range = rvHootFrame.computeHorizontalScrollRange();
    int extent = rvHootFrame.computeHorizontalScrollExtent();

    float percentage = (xOffset / (float)(range - extent));
    float seekto = percentage * TOTAL_VIDEO_IN_PX;
    Log.d(TAG, "computeHorizontalScrollOffset: (xOffset,range,extent,percentage,seekto) = ("+xOffset+", "+range+", "+extent+", "+(percentage*100)+"%, "+seekto+")");

    return seekto;
}
```

[image]

See the above screenshot
I Constantly scroll the recyclerview, but at random scroll it give unproper scrolloffset value (see the highlighted log)

Any Help Guys..